# Asp Classic return specific http status code

Tags: http, asp-classic, http-status-codes

How can I return a specific http status code from an asp classic?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
 Response.Status = "404 File Not Found"
```

> A string which specifies the value of
>   status line of the server. It is
>   included in HTTP headers of the
>   response. This string should contain
>   **both three digit code** and a brief
>   explanation for it e.g. "404 File Not
>   Found".

[The ASP Response Object](http://psacake.com/web/gz.asp)