# catching c# error on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to have a C# exception caught clientside, currently we have a section where a logged in user gets a delete link, if clicked we do a check to make sure the user is still logged in before deleting.  if not logged in anymore, the code throws and exception.

```
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public static void DeleteComment(Guid commentId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                UserEntity currentUser = ((UserEntity)Membership.GetUser());
                .. do work
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpException(401, "401");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

this error goes to the javascript code, which then is checked:

```
if (result.responseJSON.Message == "401") {
```

this works fine in our local environment, the Message field contains 401 and the result.responseJSON.ExceptionType contains "System.Web.HttpException", but when trying in our staging environment we get a 500 error code instead and the ExceptionType is ""

I've tried remote dugging and I see the exception occurring when not logged in, it's thrown but when it hits the client side code it's always 500.

Comment: You could probably just return the error in the response status code, [like in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649852/asp-net-web-service-i-would-like-to-return-error-403-forbidden).

Comment: Here is a discussion of this issue, along with some ideas for workarounds:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612970/throwing-an-httpexception-always-sends-back-http-500-error

Comment: I tried @MikeSmithDev link and that worked, still not sure why what I had would not work outside of our local machines, but regardless the method used in the link worked on both machines.

Comment: You wouldn't get anything outside because no matter what happens, you are returning void from your function.