# classic asp response code

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

We currently have a classic asp 404 error page. By default, it's returning a status code 200 error, and we want it to return a 404 error code. How do you set the status code for a page in classic asp (vbscript)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp Classic return specific http status code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456110/asp-classic-return-specific-http-status-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp Classic return specific http status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456110/asp-classic-return-specific-http-status-code)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the Response object:

```
Response.Status = "404 Not found"
```

Comment: @gleasonomicon--And make sure it's either at the top of the page, or response buffering is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, 200 is a status code `OK`, not an error, but nevertheless, the basic idea is that you need to tell the Response stream to return 404 (Not found) for the status code. [Here's one way](http://gsitecrawler.com/articles/error-404-200.asp) to do that.